# How to serve images from a different root when a certain page of the website. Nginx

Tags: regex, image, nginx

I don't have much experience with regex, and less in an Nginx context, so this one is a difficult one for me.

What I want is that when I'm on a especific page (not subfolder) the server takes images from a different root.

My current configuration to handle images in all the pages of my website right now is this one.

```
location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif) {
        root /usr/share/nginx/nginxTestPHP/media;
    }
```

And I'd like that when I'm in the page **example.com/My-Profile** the server handles the images from */usr/share/nginx/nginxTestPHP/media/uploads*, my idea is something like this, if it makes any sense.

```
location ~* /My-Profile/*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif) {
        root /usr/share/nginx/nginxTestPHP/media/uploads;
    }
```

Obviously this one doesn't work otherwise I wouldn't be here asking this, so for the regex pros out there, what would be the solution for this one ?

Also how would I apply this in 2 different pages in the same regex, something like ***(My-Profile|Configuration)*** is my idea.

***My Nginx configuration***

```
server {
    listen       81;
    listen  [::]:81;
    server_name  IP;

    client_max_body_size 4M;

    charset UTF-8;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log warn;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access_log main;

        rewrite ^(/.*)\.html(\?.*)?$ $1$2 permanent;
        rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

        root /usr/share/nginx/nginxTestPHP/PHP;

        index index.html index.htm Inicio.php Index.php;

        location / {
                try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
        }

        location @extensionless-php {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass app:9000;
                fastcgi_index Inicio.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ^~ /vendor/ {
                deny all;
                return 403;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

location ^~ /en/ {
    try_files $uri/.php $uri.php $uri/ @rewrite;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass app:9000;
    fastcgi_index Index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }

location ^~ /Blog/ {
    try_files $uri/.php $uri.php $uri/ @rewrite;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass app:9000;
    fastcgi_index Index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }


    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(en|Blog)(/.*\.(png|jpg|svg|ico))$ $2 last;
        return 404;
    }


    location ~ \.css {
        root /usr/share/nginx/nginxTestPHP/CSS;
        default_type text/css;
        add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
    }

    location ~ \.js {
        root /usr/share/nginx/nginxTestPHP/JavaScript;
        default_type text/javascript;
        add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
    }

    location ~ \.txt {
        root /usr/share/nginx/nginxTestPHP/PHP;
    }
    
    location ~* ^/Mi-Perfil/([^/]+\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif))$ {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/nginxTestPHP/media/uploads/$1;
    }

    location ~* \.(png|jpg|svg|ico|jpeg|gif) {
        root /usr/share/nginx/nginxTestPHP/media;
    }

    error_page  405     =200 $uri;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/nginxTestPHP/PHP;
        try_files $uri /Inicio.php;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your regex is broken, it is a dot (`.`) in PCRE patterns that acts as a wildcard, not an asterisk one. If you want to match any non-zero number of characters except a `/` one, you can use `[^/]+` regex pattern:

   ```
   location ~* /My-Profile/[^/]+\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ { ... }
   ```

   or to ensure that an URI started exactly with `/My-Profile/` add a `^` anchor (matches start of the string):

   ```
   location ~* ^/My-Profile/[^/]+\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ { ... }
   ```
2. Check the difference between [`root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) and [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) nginx directives. With your configuration nginx will search the files inside the `/usr/share/nginx/nginxTestPHP/media/uploads/My-Profile` folder. Use an `alias` directive instead:

   ```
   location ~* ^/My-Profile/[^/]+\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ {
       alias /usr/share/nginx/nginxTestPHP/media/uploads;
   }
   ```

**Update**

I think I made a serious mistake. Since this is a regex matching location an `alias` directive argument should contain full path to image file *with* filename:

```
location ~* ^/My-Profile/([^/]+\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif))$ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/nginxTestPHP/media/uploads/$1;
}
```

Comment: Only the last one should work. Do you know that regex matching locations are checked from first to the last one? Do you place this one **before** the `location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif) { ... }`?

Comment: Yes I knew and yes I placed it before the normal location handler, and it didn't work :(

Comment: If you talk about the prefix location ('`location / { ... }`), those have a lower priority than the regex ones. Both `location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif) { ... }` and `location ~* ^/My-Profile/([^/]+\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif))$ { ... }` are regex matching locations and the first one should follow the second in your configuration. I checked my answer locally and it worked as expected. Unless you add your full configuration to your question, I can't help you further.

Comment: Configuration is posted.

Comment: I checked your configuration locally, it works for me. Are you trying to access URLs like `example.com/Mi-Perfil/somefile.jpg` and not the `example.com/Mi-Perfil/subfolder/somefile.jpg`? The latter one won't work with the given regex.

Comment: I'm not trying to enter images through the URL like `example.com/Mi-Perfil/somefile.jpg`, I'm on the URL `example.com/Mi-Perfil` what I want is that when the HTML of the page has an `<img src="SomeImage.jpg" />`, that src is searched in /media/uploads, not in /media

Answer (score 0):

Little experience with Nginx here but the regex part looks relatively simple to fix - try using:

```
location ~* /My-Profile/.+\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/nginxTestPHP/media/uploads;
}
```

Note the `.+` after `My-Profile/` and the end-of-string anchor (`$`) - I'm assuming you want to only match images, not a URI like `stackoverflow.com/test.png/somepage`.

From the little research I did, you may also want to look into nginx maps, especially if you're looking to do this for multiple profile pages all following the same URI pattern.